# Android Emulator Crashing with Runtime Error r6025 Pure Virtual Function Call

Tags: android, sdk, android-emulator, r6025

My Android Emulator is Closing along with this error message

> Runtime Error r6025 Pure Virtual Function Call

It's occurring very frequently,what should I do to overcome this error.Any help regarding this is Appreciated.

Comment: check here  http://www.fixerrs.com/2014/05/Fix-runtime-error-r6025.html

Comment: i followed that process and again i am getting same error @Anil

Comment: Me too. Frequent and irritating problem.